# how to implement my unban code into a working code

Tags: discord.js

how can I implement my code to an actual code?
I wanted to unban a user

the code that I used for the unbanning is:

```
const id = interaction.options.get('target')?.value;
guild.members.unban(id);
```

how can I implement this to a code that executes this command when a user says something like:
":unban @user"

Comment: What do you mean by "*implement my code to an actual code*"?

Comment: I'm bad at English and as I said before how can I implement my unban code into a code that executes my unban command when a user says something like .unban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just put it in an `message` event (`messageCreate` in v13). You can then put your code in there. You can't however use the `interaction` if you want it to start with `.unban`.

```js
client.on("message", async msg => {
  if(msg.content.startsWith(".unban")) {
    const [, ...args] = msg.content.split(/ +/g)
    const user = msg.mentions.users.first() || await client.users.fetch(args[0])
    if(!user) return msg.channel.send("No user found")
    msg.guild.members.unban(user.id || user)
  }
})
```

Warning: This is incomplete, untested code. It may have some problems. If you have any, just comment below.

Comment: IT ACTUALLY WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH!